# How can I get socket room name in socket 1.4?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm looking for a method or a command line to get the socket room name if possible. Any ideas or tips are highly appreciated! For example if the name of the room is 'roomName', I'm looking to get this value, ty!

Comment: What do you mean "get the socket room name"?  Sockets can be in many rooms and, in fact, every socket is put it in a room by default and other rooms you add it to would be in addition to that.  Are yo trying to get a list of the rooms a given socket is in?

Comment: If you do socket.join(roomName), the room gets an value, I'm trying ti get the name of the room which is roomName..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A socket.io socket can be in multiple rooms.  In fact, it is automatically placed into a room with the same name as the `socket.id` value when the socket first connects.

If what you're trying to do is get a list of all the rooms a socket is in on the server-side of the connection, you can use `socket.rooms`.  That is an object that lists all the rooms the socket is in.  If you want just an array of room names the socket is in, you can use this:

```
let rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms);
```

If you want to eliminate the auto-generated room that matches the `socket.id`, you can do this:

```
let rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms).filter(function(item) {
    return item !== socket.id;
});
```

---

If you're trying to get this information from the client-end of things, it is not available from the client-side socket.  You would have to ask the server which rooms this client is in or you'd have to have a system where the client was kept notified of what rooms it was being put in and it kept track of that data.  The socket.io client does not know what rooms it is in.

---

One other thing to be careful of in socket.io.  I've seen some asynchronous behavior in joining rooms which means that if you `socket.join("someRoom")` and then immediately query `socket.rooms`, the new room might not be there yet.  If you query `socket.rooms` on the next tick, it will be there.  I'm not sure if this always happens or just happens in some circumstances.