# Check in what room is a specified client socket io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am trying to make a 'seen' function for my socket.io chat. For this, I need to know in what room is the receiver client.How can I do this? Example if a user send a message to a group I want to check all user's currently room from the group and then say if they are in this room or not.

Comment: If you're trying to do this from the server, then the exact code is in this answer: [How can I get socket room name in socket 1.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836410/how-can-i-get-socket-room-name-in-socket-1-4/39836710#39836710).

Comment: If you're trying to do this from the client, you can't.  You have to ask the server because only the server knows what rooms a socket is in unless you somehow keep track of what rooms you requested to be in on the client.  Only servers can add/remove a socket from a room.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this, is by maintaining a list of connected sockets on the server, add them as they connect (but check for duplicates). You can see what rooms a socket is part of by using `socket.rooms`. A user can be part of multiple rooms also, so iirc, socket.rooms is an array or collection of some variety.

Using the below code, you can get a list of users that share a room with the requesting socket.

```
var connected_sockets = [];

io.on("connection",function(socket){
    socket.on("request", function(msg){
        var socket = get_user_connection(socket.id);
        if(socket == null){
            connected_sockets.push(socket); //add if not already
        }
        var users_in_same_room = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < socket.rooms.length; x++){
            for(var y = 0 ; y < connected_sockets.length; y++){
                if(connected_sockets[y].id == socket.id) continue;
                if(is_user_in_room(connected_sockets[y],socket.rooms[x])){
                    //they share a room
                    users_in_same_room.push(connected_sockets[y]);
                } else {
                    //they do not share a room
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

var get_user_connection = function(socket_id){
    for(var x = 0 ; x < connected_sockets; x++){
        if(connected_sockets[x].id == socket_id){
            return connected_sockets[x];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var is_user_in_room = function(socket,room_name){
    for(var x = 0 ; x < connected_sockets[x].rooms.length; x++){
        if(connected_sockets[x].rooms[y] == room_name){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Something like the above. I'm sure you could optimize it, but that's the jist of things.